# Maximum value for the absolute of Numbers in Excel and C# programatically

Tags: c#, excel

I am programming an application which uses data from excel file.  in order to to get the maximum number in a range of column, I do the following:

```
 xlRng = sheetReal.Range[sheetReal.Cells[11, i], sheetReal.Cells[41, i]];
 sheetReal.Cells[UsedRow , i].Value = excelApp.WorksheetFunction.Max(xlRng);
```

which is fine. but now I want to have the maximum value for the absolutes of numbers. How can I get that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
excelApp.WorksheetFunction.Max(xlRng);
```

To:

```
excelApp.WorksheetFunction.Max(-excelApp.WorksheetFunction.Min(xlRng), excelApp.WorksheetFunction.Max(xlRng));
```